# Change Gatsby Permalinks to Non Pretty

Tags: gatsby, permalinks, url-scheme

I have an old php website that i want to transfer to Gatsby. However, it uses the following permalinks structure:

```
http://example.com/?qa=2/my-awesome-post
```

I am using the Gatsby Starter Blog theme, however, the urls there are as follow:

```
http://example.com/my-awesome-post
```

It is crutial to be able to adjust the permalink structure because of SEO reasons. However, if I try to just change folder structure, there is an error that "?" character is not allowed in a file or folder name. Is there a way to include a special character in the url structure of a Gatsby website? Please help!

Comment: Would the path always be in the format of `/?qa=2/my-awesome-post`. You could easily adjust the paths when using `createPage` in `gatsby-node.js`

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating those pages from scratch by just creating new `.js` file into the `pages` folder you might consider overwriting the `onCreatePage` method in `gatsby-node.js`.

Example:

```
exports.onCreatePage = ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { createPage, deletePage } = actions;

  // First delete the incoming page that was automatically created by Gatsby
  deletePage(page);

  // then create a new one with proper url
  return createPage({
    ...page,
    path: 'update-to-your-needs' 
  })
}
```

If they are being created dynamically for example from markdown files you can overwrite how they are created in `gatsby-node.js` as well.

Comment: for some reason it is not working when I add a question mark (probably because it is restricted symbol)? It is only working when I try without the question mark: `qa=2/my-awesome-post` Urls are updated correctly but the single page is not loading on click.

Comment: Yeah. That's due to how servers and browsers implement the question mark. I doubt there is anything you can do about it. The only thing that comes to my mind is to create a permanent redirect from the old URL to the new one in Nginx or any other web server.

Comment: Do you know How i can do the url redirects with Gatsby?

Comment: The only thing that comes in my mind is dirty and I cannot really recommend it, but it should work. In your main index.js file you could set up a JS script that would look for any query params and then redirect accordingly.